# Exclude a value in JSON object when passing as request to API based on condition

Tags: java, json

i want to exclude a value from JSON Object when passing as input to an API based on the condition. i.e for some scenario that partcular key:value is not requried ,but for some  that key:value is need .

Input JSON is as Below

```
{
  "customerNumber" : "6634374019",
  "ea" : "",
  "source" : "Test",
  "dataCentre" : "US",
  "requestId" : "CSP-QA-1574"
}
```

and Class for above is as follows

```
public class order
{
   @JsonProperty(value="customerNumber")
   public String customerNumber;
   @JsonProperty(value="ea")
   public String ea;
   @JsonProperty(value="source")
   public String source;
   @JsonProperty(value="dataCentre")
   public String dataCentre;
   @JsonProperty(value="requestId")
   public String requestId;
    //constructor for assiging data
     //getters and setters
}
```

Can any body please help  me in this.  i do not want to pass **"ea" key:value** in JSON input for some scenarios and in some i need to pass. how to achieve this.

thnaks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@JsonIgnore
```

And be happy.

Cheers

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply .i have used the above mentioned working fine , but i have 2 test cases for the same scenario in this one need the ea value and the other it should ignore. how to handle that one .

Comment: try to use properties and not fields!! Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this then I would have gone with a slightly different approach.

```
 JsonObject gsonObject=new JsonObject();
        gsonObject.addProperty("ea","value");
```

like that conditionally addProperty().
Since I don't have enough rep So I am putting it like answer instead of comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use @JsonIgnoreProperties on class level if you want to ignore any values that are not passed. If you want to ignore a single value, you can use @JsonIgnore at member level.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"Ignore 1", "Ignore 2"})
   class Sample {
```

or

```
class Sample {
    private String xyz;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String ignorethis;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply .i have used the above mentioned working fine , but i have 2 test cases for the same scenario in this one need the ea value and the other it should ignore. how to handle that one .

Comment: You can pass the value even if you have given @JsonIgnore for that field. You can update the assert statement to verify if the field is passed.If your response differs with 'passing' the value and 'not passing', then same way,  assertions should help.